# How do I validate multiple fields from a single location in CakePHP?

Tags: validation, cakephp, field, cakephp-2.3

I wanna validate multiple fields at one place. So in a form I have included 4 fields
as follows

1. facebook_link
2. twitter_link
3. google_plus_link
4. linked_in_link

The user atleast type any one field of above. Please help me to get the solution like, the user types anyone of the links in the form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you may add your own Validation Methods.

```
public $validate = array(
    'facebook_link' => array(
        'rule'    => array('validateLink'),
        'message' => '...'
    ),
    'twitter_link' => array(
        'rule'    => array('validateLink'),
        'message' => '...'
    ),
    'google_plus_link' => array(
        'rule'    => array('validateLink'),
        'message' => '...'
    ),
    'linked_in_link' => array(
        'rule'    => array('validateLink'),
        'message' => '...'
    ),
);

public function validateLink($link) {
    $allFieldsAreEmpty = (
        empty($this->data[$this->alias]['facebook_link']) &&
        empty($this->data[$this->alias]['twitter_link']) &&
        empty($this->data[$this->alias]['google_plus_link']) &&
        empty($this->data[$this->alias]['linked_in_link'])
    );

    return !$allFieldsAreEmpty;
}
```

Comment: please describe more what you did and what you call not working? (e.g error, unexpected behavior)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for you.

```
public $validate = array(
    'facebook_link' => array(
        'rule'    => array('customValidation','facebook_link'),
        'message' => 'Please enter facebook link.'
    ),
    'twitter_link' => array(
        'rule'    => array('customValidation','twitter_link'),
         'message' => 'Please enter twitter link.'
    ),
    'google_plus_link' => array(
        'rule'    => array('customValidation'),
         'message' => 'Please enter google plus link.'
    ),
    'linked_in_link' => array(
        'rule'    => array('customValidation'),
         'message' => 'Please enter linkedin link.'
    ),
);

function customValidation($data , $filed) {
    if(empty($data[$filed])) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```